How to solve the black screen issue on Vs-Code
I was working with my vs-code and I had a sudden power outage on my windows 10 pro machine, when I restarted my machine and windows completed its disc repair thing, everything seems to be working fine except my vs-code. when I boot it, it get's stuck on a black screen. The black screen
I have tried starting with compatibility mode & disabling gpu, that didn't work. I also uninstalled and installed a much later version of vs-code and it still didn't work
